# Ограничение доступа для пользователя

Tags: linux, доступ

Дистрибутив Debian GNU/Linux.

Как ограничить пользователю доступ ко всему, кроме выполнения одного файла?
Ну, и соответственно, этот пользователь должен мочь проверить, запущен ли этот файл, и если нет, то запустить.

Comment: Что бы пользователь мог проверить запущено ли что то ему как минимум нужен доступ к команде ps. что бы он вообще находился в системе ему нужен доступ к шеллу. А что бы это все работало - нужен доступ еще к куче библиотек. так что сначала надо опредлиться с тем к чему именно надо ограничить доступ.

Comment: Есть один файл. Пользователь должен мочь проверять только запущен ли этот файл, запускать этот файл и закрывать его.

Comment: так, может, просто микро-интерфейс (на основе http или ssh или telnet или т.п.) на коленке написать, который будет принимать три команды («запустить», «убить», «проверить, работает ли»)?

Comment: и обязательно уточните, каким образом пользователь должен иметь возможность общаться с системой: это должен быть интерктивный вход или удалённое подключение по какому-нибудь протоколу (и по какому именно).

Comment: Будет удаленное подключение

Answer (score 3):

«искоробочного» средства, насколько мне известно, нет.

если используется аутентификация по ключу, то можно в файле `~/.authorized_keys` перед ключом пользователя добавить параметр `command=/путь/к/вашему/скрипту` (подробности смотрите в [man sshd, секция «authorized_keys file format»](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man8/sshd.8?query=sshd#x415554484f52495a45445f4b4559532046494c4520464f524d4154)).

а в `/путь/к/вашему/скрипту` (файл должен иметь бит исполнимости, разумеется) написать обработчик примерно такого вида:

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" in
  start)
    # здесь код запуска того, что вам нужно
    ;;
  stop)
    # здесь код остановки того, что вам нужно
    ;;
  status)
    # здесь код, проверяющий статус того, что вам нужно,
    # и выводящий информацию в stdout. эту информацию увидит пользователь
    ;;
  *)
    # неизвестная команда. возвращаем пользователю сообщение об ошибке
    echo "unknown command"
    ;;
esac
```

когда пользователь выполнит команду `ssh имя@хост start`, то будет выполнен этот ваш скрипт, а строка `start` будет передана скрипту в переменной окружения `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND`.

строки `start`/`stop`/`status` использованы лишь для иллюстрации. вы можете использовать что угодно иное.

Answer (score 2):

Что бы вводить такие серьезные разграничения нужно как минимум познакомится
с selinux. С его помощью можно прописывать любые роли но тема надо признать
довольно сложная для отдельно взятого случая

Answer (score 1):

добавка к ответу **alexander barakin** (я новое узнал).

все ниже изложенное я использовал в своей практике. излагаю кратко, основные моменты.

---

доступ по **ssh** (файл **/etc/ssh/sshd_config**):

параметр
AllowUsers username1, username2

разрешит подключение по ssh только пользователям username1, username2

---

ограничение полномочий в системе (файл **/etc/sudoers**. т.е. когда пользователь username1 или username2 уже залогинен в системе по ssh):

*синтаксис: [пользователь] [хост]=([кем может стать]) [что может сделать]*

username1 ALL=(root) /usr/bin/scp

username2 ALL=(root) /sbin/reboot

%users ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/sbin/poweroff

---

результат:

пользователь username1 сможет использовать scp (*скопировать файл <имя файла> на комп host2 через ssh используя пароль своей учетной записи на компе host2 в каталог /home/username1. ключ -P это номер порта, используемого ssh на компе host2 (по дефолту номер порта 22). ключ -v чтобы был виден процесс копирования. scp выполняется с повышенными привилегиями)*.

```
sudo scp -v -P 222 <имя файла> username1@host2:/home/username1
```

пользователь username2 сможет использовать reboot используя пароль своей учетной записи:

```
sudo reboot
```

пользователи группы users смогут использовать poweroff без ввода паролей:

```
sudo poweroff
```

дальше дело за вами: для кого и что разрешить/запретить/ограничить.