# Как выполнить запуск скрипта от суперпользователя без пароля?

Tags: linux, sudo

Как выполнить запуск sh скрипта без пароля?

Comment: близко по смыслу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/483292/178576

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Все можно настроить через файл `/etc/sudoers`. Вот способ как можно перезапускать все службы (`sudo service ...`) от пользователя `userlogin`.

### 1. Создаем специальную группу для запуска, которой дадим необходимые права:

```
sudo groupadd sudo-restrict
```

### 2. Добавляем пользователя `userlogin` в эту группу:

```
sudo usermod -aG sudo-restrict userlogin
```

### 3. Редактируем файл `/etc/sudoers` с помощью `visudo`:

```
sudo visudo
```

Необходимо ставить в конце следующее:

```
%sudo-restrict    ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service
```

`/usr/sbin/service` - путь к программе необходимо указывать абсолютный. В вашем случае это будет путь к вашему скрипту. Я использую служебную команду `service`

### 4. Проверяем

Заходим под пользователем `userlogin` и выполняем

```
sudo service mysqld restart
```

Сервис перезапустится без ввода пароля.

### PS

В конце `/etc/sudoers` можно раскомментировать эту строку: `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d`, и записывать все настройки в отдельные файлы в каталоге `/etc/sudoers.d`

[Мана](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)#%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0_sudo_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E_%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B2_/etc/sudoers.d_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: добавлю, что группу можно не создавать, а дать права конкретному пользователю...

Answer (score 0):

Настраиваем доступ по **ssh**. Сначала генерируем ключ :

```
удалённый_пользователь$ ssh-keygen
```

**без** пароля ключа.

Оставляем секретный ключ юзера себе. *( ~/.ssh/id_rsa )*

Регистрируем публичный ключ **root**-у.

```
root# mkdir -p  /root/.ssh
root# chmod 700 /root/.ssh
root# cat id_rsa.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Рисуем нужный скрипт *( root-пользователем )* и удалённо запускаем :

```
удалённый_пользователь$ ssh -p 12345 root@192.168.0.66 /root/скрипт
```

Если скрипт только написали, тогда копируйте сначала :

```
удалённый_пользователь$ scp -P 12345 ./скрипт root@192.168.0.66:/root/
```

Если только на локальном компе это надо сделать, то вместо адреса рисуйте *localhost*. Если вы не меняли стандартный ssh порт  22  на 12345 , то опцию задания порта можно опустить.

Comment: Непонятно, что такое «пользователь с root правами» и откуда `./скрипт` возьмёт себе root-права

Comment: Скрипт будет работать с правами **rootuser**.

Comment: Но как rootuser связан с суперпользователем, всё ещё непонятно

Comment: **rootuser** должен быть в группе **root**. И в некоторых системах, пользователь **root** - вообще отключён.

Comment: Непонятно, как группа root связана с правами суперпользователя. Само по себе наличие группы root не даёт никому никаких прав (кроме доступа к файлам с этой группой, и то не ко всем)

Comment: Ну тогда группа **sudo** может быть поможет.

Comment: В популярных дистрибутивах группы admin и sudo по умолчанию настроены на требование пароля. Так что ответ на вопрос не получился

Comment: Причём здесь ssh? В вопросе вроде ни слова нет об удалённом доступе.

Comment: @Beast Winterwolf **ssh** подключение не подразумевает удалённость. Всего лишь предлагаю способ без парольного подключения пользователя.

Comment: @AlexGlebe но в итоге группы admin и sudo всё равно требуют пароль

Comment: @AlexGlebe исправил инструкцию чтоб у скрипта были рут права.

Answer (score 0):

Я согласен с ответом Total Pusher, но сам обычно использую более простой и универсальный способ:

1. Запускаю `sudo visudo`
2. Добавляю в конец `username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` (укажите свой username)
3. Сохраняю

Разница в том, что никаких особых групп и пользователей я не создаю и в результате можно запускать любые скрипты и команды без пароля (мне достаточно того, что юзер вводит пароль при запуске сессии).

UPD: Как метко подметил andreymal, этот способ создаёт дыру в безопасности системы и использовать его на постоянной основе не рекомендуется.

Comment: Пользователь скачивает сторонний скрипт, запускает без sudo, но внутри у него прописан sudo, который без пароля уничтожает систему.

Comment: Пользователь пользуется уязвимой версией ghostscript и скачивает картинку с котиками, которая с помощью беспарольного sudo опять же уничтожает систему автоматически сразу после скачивания файла (даже открывать его необязательно).

Comment: @andreymal Вы правы, этот способ не безопасный. Но как минимум для временного пользования - вариант.

Comment: @andreymal а я все мечтаю о "виндовом" который спросит "virt-manager хочет права. Дать? да-нет". а так приходиться свой "оченьдлинныйисложныйпароль" вводить по несколько раз в час