# Доступ к папке под пользователем с правами root

Tags: linux, centos

Centos

Есть пользователь в группе test, у него есть права sudo, какие права выставить папке opt/sce-data/storage (root владелец), чтобы user не мог изменить права доступа, доступ к папке имеет только root.

Comment: Что конкретно имеется в виду под фразой «права sudo»?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону расширенных атрибутов.

Answer (score 2):

Если у пользователя есть права на выполнение команды sudo, он может абсолютно всё, как и root. Потому что sudo (в самом распространённом варианте использования) как раз и подразумевает, что действие выполняется от имени пользователя root.

Comment: Нет. [Можно назначить определенные команды на sudo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/968175/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F/968195#968195)