# Не получается создать файл на сервере через php + bash

Tags: php, linux, apache, bash

Пробую создать файл для sites-avalibe, использую для этого php для ввода данных и bash чтобы это все заработало, но я потерпел фиаско, правда я не понимаю в чем проблема, ведь если я попытаюсь исполнить скрипт из консоли все работает, а через веб-страницу нет

php файл с формой

```
if ($answer == True){
        echo '
            <form action="" method="post">
                <lable>Site NAME:</lable>
                <input type="text" name="sname" />
                <br><br>
                <lable>github url:</lable>
                <input type="text" name="github" />
                <input type="submit" name="sub" />
            </form>
            ';

            if (!empty($_POST['sub'])){
                if (!empty($_POST['sname'])){
                    $site = $_POST['sname'];
                    $output = shell_exec('./create_site.sh '. $site);
                    echo "<pre> uptime: $output</pre>";
                }
            }
    }
```

bash скрипт:

```
cd ~
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
printf '<VirtualHost *:80>\n
    ServerAdmin marktamarov2001@gmail.com\n
    ServerName '$1'.queryberry.ru\n
    ServerAlias www.'$1'.queryberry.ru\n
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dev.QueryBerry/sites/'$1'/\n
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/dev.QueryBerry/sites/'$1'\n
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log\n
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined\n
</VirtualHost>' > "$1".queryberry.ru.conf

sudo a2ensite "$1".queryberry.ru.conf
sudo systemctl restart apache2

echo site was created
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## 1. Ограничения файловой системы

> если я попытаюсь исполнить скрипт из консоли все работает, а через веб-страницу нет

Первая причина - права на файлы.

```
ls -ld /etc/apache2/sites-available
```

выведет что-то похожее:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct  8 14:16 /etc/apache2/sites-available
```

Получается, что права на запись только у владельца (`root`). Введите в консоли `whoami` - скорее всего вы и есть root.

А через вебсервер php-скрипт запускается от имени другого пользователя и группы, это устанавливается в настройках `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. Поищем эти настройки:

```
grep -P "User|Group" /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Выведет:

```
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
```

Поищем эти переменные:

```
grep -rP "APACHE_RUN_USER|APACHE_RUN_GROUP" /etc/apache2/
```

Выведет:

```
/etc/apache2/envvars:export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
/etc/apache2/envvars:export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

Получается, что апач работает от имени `www-data` и группы `www-data`.

Чтобы разрешить доступ, нужно сменить владельца:

```
sudo chown www-data /etc/apache2/sites-available
```

либо где-то в конце `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` поменять

```
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

на другой каталог, доступный для записи `www-data`. Что делает `a2ensite`? По сути, она делает симлинки из `sites-available` в `sites-enabled`, поэтому `a2ensite` после такой перенастройки (смена `IncludeOptional`) не обязательно выполнять.

## 2. Ограничение open_basedir

Опция [open_basedir](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) дополнительно ограничивает PHP какими-то каталогами. Поискать можно так:

```
grep -r open_basedir /etc/apache2
```

У меня вывело:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/included.site.ru.conf:  php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/pusher/www/site.ru:/home/pusher/www/mod-tmp:/tmp"
```

Получается, что когда Apache запускает скрипт сайта `site.ru`, этот скрипт ограничен тремя перечисленными через `:` каталогами.

Удалите `open_basedir` или добавьте каталог `/etc/apache2/sites-available` в эту настройку.

## 3. Ограничение на запуск sudo

> sudo a2ensite "$1".queryberry.ru.conf
>
> sudo systemctl restart apache2

Пользователь `www-data`, от имени которого запускается скрипт, скорее всего не имеет прав на запуск административных команд с помощью sudo.

Как настроить запуск `sudo ...` без ввода пароля я подробно описал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/968175/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f/968195#968195)

Вам нужно запускать две команды: `a2ensite` и `systemctl`. Выполните:

```
sudo visudo
```

Затем необходимо вставить в конце следующее:

```
www-data    ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/a2ensite
www-data    ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl
```

В данном случае спец. группу создавать не надо, мы просто даем доступ конкретному пользователю.

## Тестирование и отладка

Делайте все поэтапно, смотря результат. Чтобы не запускать каждый раз php-скрипт и ломать голову, зайдите от имени апача и выполняйте аналогичные команды. Давайте зайдем под `www-data`:

```
sudo su
su www-data -s /bin/bash
```

вот так можно понять, что первый пункт работает:

```
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
touch site.ru
# выведет это:
touch: cannot touch ‘site.ru’: Permission denied
```

Ага. Не настроено.

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
# выведет это:
We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo] password for www-data:
```

Ага. Требует пароль. Не настроено.

Ограничение `open_basedir` можно проверить только через браузер.

PS. По сути, вы делаете свою реализацию давно решенной задачи по добавлению виртуальных хостов через веб-панель. Насколько безопасно вы это сделаете - зависит от вас. Если что, есть уже готовые решения: `cPanel`, `ISPmanager` и другие.