# От имени какого пользователя запускает крон sh-файл?

Tags: debian, cron, права-доступа

В крон добавлено задание на запуск sh-файла. Файл принадлежит root-root с правами 644.
Если ничего не менять, то скрипт не выполняется - нет прав.

Как вариант, можно поставить права на файл 755 - тогда все работает.
Может быть корректнее, не менять права, а изменить принадлежность файла, сменив его владельца и группу?

Искал, но не смог найти, какому пользователю передать эти права, чтобы скрипт по крону запускался.
ОС - Linux Debian 10.

////////////////////////

Всем спасибо за участие!

Добавление **/bin/bash** перед именем скрипта решило проблему запуска не меняя атрибуты файла с 644 на 755.

Comment: Бит выполнения должен стоять в любом случае независимо от пользователя

Comment: И вы всегда можете узнать текущего пользователя командой `whoami` или чем-то подобным

Comment: Если по каким-то причинам вы не хотите делать скрипт исполняемым (а, судя по всему, у вас таких причин нет), то его всегда можно запустить как `/bin/bash /path/to/your/script.sh`

Comment: Александр, спасибо!

Добавление /bin/bash перед именем скрипта решило проблему запуска не меняя права с 644 на 755.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> От имени какого пользователя запускает крон sh-файл?

От любого.

У каждого пользователя есть свой набор cron-задач. Крон-демон запускает задачи (скрипты) от имени одного из пользователя: root, обычного пользователя, или системного пользователя.

- `crontab -l` - получить задачи текущего пользователя
- `sudo crontab -l -u mysql` - получить задачи другого пользователя, в данном случае mysql. Так как вы авторизованы как обычный пользователь, а обычные пользователи не могут видеть/редактировать задачи других пользователей, понадобилось повышение прав до пользователя `root` через механизм `sudo`.
- `sudo su`, `crontab -l -u mysql` - то же самое, только сначала мы авторизовались под `root`
- `sudo cat /etc/crontab` - выводит системные крон-задачи. В этом файле, в отличие от обычного крона, есть столбец `user` - от какого пользователя будет запущена задача. А чтобы обычные пользователи не могли редактировать это файл, редактировать может только root.
- также есть такие каталоги в `/etc`: `cron.d/` `cron.daily/` `cron.hourly/` `cron.monthly/` `cron.weekly/`, они для системных задач, ознакомьтесь с содержимым самостоятельно. Там также прописан пользователь.

> Файл принадлежит root-root с правами 644. Если ничего не менять, то скрипт не выполняется - нет прав

Скрипт не выполняется потому что атрибут выполнения не выставлен. Вам надо решить на каком уровне поставить этот атрибут - владелец, группа или все. Допустим, файл имеет атрибуты 644 и владельца:группу root:root.

Чтобы скрипт запускался, нужно

- `chmod u+x` или `chmod 764` - для владельца (root)
- `chmod g+x` или `chmod 674` - для группы (root)
- `chmod o+x` или `chmod 665` - для всех остальных

> Может быть корректнее, не менять права, а изменить принадлежность файла, сменив его владельца и группу?

Скрипт получает те же права/привилегии, что и пользователь, от имени которого он запущен. Это значит, что он будет иметь доступ/создавать файлы от этого же пользователя, а также выполнять другие задачи/скрипты.

- если нужен неограниченный доступ, то root
- если действия будут в вашем домашнем каталоге, то назначьте себя владельцем
- если скрипт будет обслуживать задачи веб-сервера apache2, назначьте владельцем apache2
- если нужны пониженные права, но нужно иметь несколько повышенных привилегий на запуск нескольких задач, назначьте владельцем обычного пользователя (или apache2 для веб-сайта) и повысьте часть привилегий через [механизм sudo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/968195/287469)

> Если по каким-то причинам вы не хотите делать скрипт исполняемым (а, судя по всему, у вас таких причин нет), то его всегда можно запустить как /bin/bash /path/to/your/script.sh

В общем-то да. Но советую разобраться как все это работает: cron, sudo, права доступа. Отложите насущную задачу, почитайте, и потом вернитесь к ней. И вы поймете всю прелесть системы Linux :)