# Как организовать локальный сервер git? (возможно через доступ по ssh)

Tags: git, ssh

Суть: есть машина с несколькими пользователями. Необходимо создать репозиторий git для этих пользователей, который бы находился **на этой же машине** (даже на том же диске).
Вариант использовать локальный протокол не устраивает, т.к. вижу при этом два похожих варианта развития:

1. если разрешить rwc* всех пользователей к репозиторию, то юзеры могут изменить сам репозиторий (имею ввиду не через push, а прямым доступом);
2. если создать отдельного пользователя и только он имел право rwc репозитория, тогда ему нужно будет также дать права на rwc home-ов реальных пользователей, а это тоже чревато.
   Если тут я ошибаюсь - прошу поправить :)

Доступ по ssh к репозиторию мне кажется наиболее защищенным в этом плане, т.к. и пользователь с сервера, и локальные пользователи не могут навредить кому-либо. Однако не знаю, можно ли организовать доступ к локальной папке через ssh. В гугле ничего не нашел по этому вопросу.

*rwc - чтение-запись-модификация

Answer (score 1, accepted):

помимо уже перечисленных огромных программ *gitea* и *gogs* стоит упомянуть и минималистичный *gitolite* (в отличие от упомянутых, он опакетирован во многих дистрибутивах, например, в *debian gnu/linux* под именем *gitolite3*).

---

но для «внутреннего упонтребления», если не требуется разграничения доступа к хранилищам, можно обойтись и вообще без установки дополнительных программ (сервер openssh стоит рассматривать как присутствующий по умолчанию).

1. создайте пользователя. например, `tig` (домашний каталог — по умолчанию — `/home/tig`, пароль на ваш вкус):

   ```
   $ sudo adduser tig
   ```

   это для дистрибутива *debian gnu/linux* и «наследников». в вашем дистрибутиве процедура создания пользователя может отличаться. см. документацию к дистрибутиву.
2. от имени этого пользователя создайте [bare-хранилище](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/542434/178576):

   ```
   $ sudo -u tig git init --bare /home/tig/repo1
   ```
3. создайте для этого пользователя каталог `~/.ssh` и файл `authorized_keys` в нём (с соответствующими правами доступа и принадлежностью):

   ```
   $ sudo -u tig mkdir /home/tig/.ssh
   $ sudo -u tig touch /home/tig/.ssh/authorized_keys
   $ sudo chmod -R go= /home/tig/.ssh
   ```
4. добавьте публичный ключ разработчика в созданный файл, только в начале строки с ключом вставьте такой текст:

   ```
   command="read c r o < <(echo \"$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND\");case $c in git-upload-pack|git-receive-pack)eval $c $r;;*)exit 1;;esac"
   ```

   в конце этой строки должен быть пробел, чтобы полный текст ключа выглядел так (команду и содержимое ключа я заменил многоточиями для наглядности):

   ```
   command="..." ssh-rsa ...
   ```

   в виде однострочника (не забудьте подставить актуальный путь и имя файла с добавляемым публичным ключом):

   ```
   $ (printf 'command="read c r o < <(echo \\"$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND\\");case $c in git-upload-pack|git-receive-pack)eval $c $r;;*)exit 1;;esac" '; cat файл.с.публичным.ключом) | sudo tee -a /home/tig/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```

   что это за `command=`? а это такая [уличная магия программы openssh](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/483337/178576). подробности смотрите в документации.

собственно, теперь всё. можете клонировать созданное хранилище, выполнять push и pull (от имени того пользователя, которому принадлежит секретная часть ключа):

```
$ git clone tig@localhost:repo1
```

понятно, что если команда выполняется на другом компьютере, вместо `localhost` надо подставить имя/ip-адрес того компьютера, где вы создавали пользователя `tig`.

чтобы создать новое хранилище, повторите шаг два, указав новое имя каталога.

чтобы добавить новый ключ, повторите шаг четыре.

Comment: Кажется, второй вариант - это то, что нужно, спасибо :) Уже и сам начал догадываться о таком способе, просто не был уверен, что можно в пределах одной машины установить ssh соединение.

Comment: конечно, можно. какая с точки зрения протокола ssh разница, к какому компьютеру подключаетесь? главное, чтобы какая-то реализация ssh-сервера принимала подключения на нужном интерфейсе. основная «фишка» изложенного мной — это как раз та самая `command="..."`. благодаря этому скрипту с данным ключом невозможно ни shell запустить, ни какую иную команду выполнить. т.е. к хранилищам будет доступ только в рамках протокола git.

Comment: По поводу ограничений действий пользователя git (в данном случае - tig) - нашел еще один способ из книги "git для профессионального программиста". В файле /etc/passwd нужно найти строку с пользователем tig и заменить оболочку с "/bin/bash" на "usr/bin/git-shell". В этом случае вход на сервер напрямую через ssh будет запрещен и от имени пользователя tig возможно выполнение только команд git.

Comment: 1. сменить оболочку проще программой *chsh*, нежели редактированием файла `/etc/passwd`. 2. замена оболочки на *git-shell* по существу примерно то же самое, что и указание команды для ключа. отличия: для разных ключей можно указать разные команды. или вообще не указывать, и тогда будет загружена текущая оболочка (`/bin/bash` и т.п.). при замене же оболочки на *git-shell* запустить обычный сеанс уже не выйдет. зато чуть проще добавлять новые команды. выбирайте, что вам удобнее.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите на [Gitea](https://gitea.io/en-us/) или [Gogs](https://gogs.io/). Минимальные усилия и у Вас будет сервер, который решит 99% задач для маленькой компании. Эти сервера можно развернуть даже на локальной машине или на рядом лежащей Raspberry Pi. На линукс сервере все подымается быстро и легко (особенно в докере). Дает хорошие возможности по администрированию и управлению.

Но если очень хочется,  то можно и полноценный Gitlab развернуть. Но это перебор.